# AWS EC2( Apache) cannot be configured for SSL with Cerbot

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ssl, amazon-ec2, certbot

I have successfully deployed an application created in Laravel to AWS EC2 (Apache) and display it over HTTP.
However, I have configured it using Cerbot to display it over HTTPS, but it is not displaying.

The work I have done is as follows

```
$ sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/
$ sudo rpm -Uvh dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-*.rpm
$ sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel*
$ sudo yum repolist all
```

I opened `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` and added the following information

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app_name/public"
ServerName "example.com"
ServerAlias "www.example.com"
</VirtualHost>

Include /etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf
```

I then restarted Apache and installed Cerbot.

```
$ sudo systemctl restart httpd
$ sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-apache
$ sudo certbot
```

You have answered Certbot's questions and received the message "Congratulations! You have successfully enabled https://example.com."

However, it is not actually displayed over https.

`/etc/httpd/conf/httpd-le-ssl.conf` is as follows.

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/app_name/public"
ServerName "online-study-room.jp"
ServerAlias "www.online-study-room.jp"
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/online-study-room.jp/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/online-study-room.jp/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Port 443 was not open in the EC2 inbound rules.